# Spring Security Custom Filter Never Called

Tags: java, spring-security

The problem is that my custom Spring Security filter is never invoked when a request comes in. During debugging, I found that in `doFilter()` in `FilterChainProxy`, my filter (`JwtAuthenticationFilter`) can be fetched:

[image]

But it's skipped. Then I found it's due to:

[image]

So the superclass of my filer, which is `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` thinks the request doesn't need authentication and it just calls `doFilter()` to pass it down. I think my configs specified that auth is needed. This specific request is `/ui/home/index.jsp`, where `\ui` is the context.

My security configs:

```
<http use-expressions="true" pattern="/**" entry-point-ref="JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint" create-session="stateless">
    <custom-filter before="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="jwtAuthenticationFilter" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    // some other intercept-url definitions    
</http>
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

And bean configs:

```
 <bean id="jwtAuthenticationFilter" class="com.pk.jjwt.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter" >
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="jwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.pk.jjwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

 <bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.pk.jjwt.JwtAuthenticationProvider" />
 <bean id="jwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.pk.jjwt.JwtAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

I wonder what might cause the filters getting skipped? I think I specified that every url pattern needs to be authenticated. I'm not sure why it thinks that request doesn't need authentication from my custom filter.

**Edit:**

So I debugged the `requiresAuthentication()` method, and found:

[image]

Basically it's evaluating `uri.endsWith("/ui/**")` and `uri` is `/ui/home/index.jsp`. It returned false, so the filter is skipped.

Comment: Try debugging the method requiresAuthenticatcation(request, response).

Comment: @Journeycorner Edited it, researching that pattern match.